# Питон, множества

Tags: python, множества

Наткнулся на вот такую задачку на питоне

В порядке убывания напечатать все целые числа из диапазона 1..10000, которые представимы в виде n * n+2k * k, но не представимы в виде 7ij+j+3 (n, k, i, j >= 0).

Не очень понимаю чего от меня хотят, можете попробовать обьяснить пожалуйста?
Только прошу не решайте эту задачу, я хочу понять  алгоритм ее решения

Спасибо :)

Comment: Что такое `*` ? Если оператор умножения, почему он не употреблен в членах `2k` и `7ij`?

Comment: насколько я понимаю, это квадрат члена,то есть
n^2+2k^2

Comment: Условие, видимо, кривое или что-то перепутано. Вторым способом можно представить любые числа, кроме 1 и 2, если положить i=0

Comment: то есть? можно поподробнее, я тугодум(

Answer (score 0):

Пройтись по числам от 10000 до 1, для каждого числа:

1. попытаться найти такие n, k для которых выполнялось бы
   ***'соотношение 1' == 'текущее число'***
2. доказать что **нельзя** найти такие i и j, для которых выполняется
   ***'соотношение 2' == 'текущее число'***

Если нашли первое и доказали второе, то выводим число, если нет, идем дальше.

Comment: Оля, даже если бы условие было корректное, то такое решение слишком расточительное. Для данного диапазона проще сгенерировать все возможные числа указанного вида и немножко поработать с множествами.

Comment: Согласна, что в лоб делать слишком расточительно, но в вопросе просили "не решать". А так да, два list comprehension => пересечение